# What kind of portfolio can I make for a DevOps engineer?

Tags: devops

I work as a DevOps engineer and I want to make a portfolio that will show what I can do regarding DevOps (my stack: k8s, Jenkins, Ansible). Developing a microservice application from scratch, and then doing DevOps for it, is too difficult a task for me, because I am not a developer (I learned Go, Python, PHP, C++, react; and my projects are not so complex - these are telegram bots, charting applications).  What can I use as a template or blanks?  It seems that if I just take any project from Github and do devops for it, it will be ineffective.